# How to add a jar in the beginning of a classpath?

Tags: java, weblogic, project, war, ear

We have a requirement to have both log4j 1.x jar (added by weblogic 10.3 by default) and log4j 2.8.x jar in our classpath. I need to add the log4j 2.8.x jar in the beginning of the classpath, so that the application picks up the log4j 2.8.x jar.

Answer (score 0):

You can add those JARs to your WAR and define them inside weblogi.xml file. 
Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<wls:weblogic-web-app
xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd
http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

     <wls:weblogic-version>12.1.1</wls:weblogic-version>
     <wls:context-root>FilterWeb</wls:context-root>
     <wls:container-descriptor>
         <wls:prefer-application-packages>
             <wls:package-name>com.oracle.foo</wls:package-name>
         </wls:prefer-application-packages>
     </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP660